# Neo4j 2.0M3 Spatial 0.12 - Spatial doesn't return any result for my query

Tags: neo4j, spatial

I am following the tutorial at http://neo4j.github.io/spatial/#rest-api-add-a-node-to-the-spatial-index to test Spatial 0.12 with Neo4j 2.0M03. I am trying SimplePointLayer example, to get the nodes within a radius.

Although it looks like everything is created (layer, index etc..) as expected and my domain nodes are indexed properly, my Cypher query or my java spatial query code do not return any result.

When I try the exact same thing with Neo4j 1.9 and Spatial 0.11, it works just fine.

Before digging this issue any further I wanted to ask Neo4j community first if this is a known issue or not. Thanks in advance.

-- Testing steps based on Peter's comment --

geo_layer.json:

```
{
    "layer" : "geom",
    "lat" : "lat",
    "lon" : "lon"
}

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @geo_layer.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer
```

geo_index.json:

```
{
    "name" : "geom",
    "config" : {
            "provider" : "spatial",
            "geometry_type" : "point",
            "lat" : "lat",
            "lon":"lon"
            }
}

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @geo_index.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node
```

geo_node.json:

```
{
    "lat" : 60.1,
    "lon" : 15.2
}

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @geo_node.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/node
```

New node's id is **5** - I started with an empty graph.

domain_node.json:

```
{
    "value": "dummy",
    "key": "dummy",
    "uri": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5"
}

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @domain_node.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/geom
```

cypher_query.json:

```
{
    "query": "start node = node:geom('withinDistance:[60.0,15.0, 100.0]') return node;"
}

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @cypher_query.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
```

The result:

```
{
  "message" : "org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.GeoPipeFlowHits.iterator()Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/ResourceIterator;",
  "exception" : "AbstractMethodError",
  "fullname" : "java.lang.AbstractMethodError",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.indexQuery(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:120)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.DelegatingOperations.indexQuery(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:107)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(EntityProducerFactory.scala:70)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(EntityProducerFactory.scala:68)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anon$1.apply(EntityProducerFactory.scala:38)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.EntityProducerFactory$$anon$1.apply(EntityProducerFactory.scala:37)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:34)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:33)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:36)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:84)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:157)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)", "scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:29)", "org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult$$anon$1.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:73)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:58)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:58)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:83)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:185)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:133)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:119)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:96)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)" ]
```

-- Alternatively --

location.json:

```
{
    "layer" : "geom",
    "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5"
}

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @location.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer
```

geo_query.json:

```
{
    "layer" : "geom",
    "distanceInKm" : "100",
    "pointX" : "15",
    "pointY" : "60"
}

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @geo_query.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance
```

returns empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding the node to the index prior to querying it via Cypher, as that creates the necessary structurs in the DB, see https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/SpatialPluginFunctionalTest.java#L268

Comment: thanks for the reply Peter. I listed the result of a new test that is mimicking the unit test you have suggested me to look at. Not sure what the error I am getting means. I have cloned the latest Spatial code from github and used for this test. My Neo4j version is 2.0M3 that I have downloaded from the site - I haven't built my self. I don't know if does it mean anything but when I follow the steps above, I see two indexes created as a result. The first one is "geom__neo4j-spatial__LayerNodeIndex__internal__spatialNodeLookup__", the second one is "geom". Any thought?

Comment: One last note. When I conduct the same test on 1.9.1, it works like a charm.